# JavaScript array and jQuery .data() comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to make my code to check the array data value and compare it with another one using jQuery, here's the code:

```
myArray = [];
function first () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        //some code...

        $(item).data("text", [i]);
        $(item).on("click", function () {
            abc($(this));
        }
    }
}

function abc (xps) {
    if ($(myArray[0]).data("text") != $(xps).data("text")) {
        myArray.push(xps);
    }

    //some code...

}
```

alert box result:

> myArray.data = undefined --on mouse click--> myArray.data = 0
>
> xps.data = 0 --------------on mouse click--> xps.data = 0

As you can see the myArray.data changed to 0, which means the above code works, but it checks for one value in the array and I want it to check for every possible value so I have implemented for loop, like this:

```
function abc (xps) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if ($(myArray[i]).data("text") != $(xps).data("text")) {
            myArray.push(xps);
        }
    }
}
```

but it suddenly stopped working, current alert box results:

> myArray.data = undefined --on mouse click--> myArray.data = undefined
>
> xps.data = 0 --------------on mouse click--> xps.data = 0

Just a quick edit:

it seems like the for loop is trying to get the value in order to execute if statement but the array is empty at the start so it is not possible, that's why I get udefined because it cannot reach the if statement. If there is any workaround, please let me know as I am completely stuck here.

Comment: so as far as I understand it, you want to push the element into an array, if the data-text is not the first one of it/not already in it?

Comment: all sorted, had to change the function since it was rather complicated